# How to randomly remove elements of same class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have about 72 divisions of class="box"

these are some black colored boxes covering my whole pages, and i want to remove these divisions one by one and randomly after the completion of on of my function.

Here is what i am doing to remove these boxes randomly,

```
function removeBoxes(){

    var erase;
            //var to store the length of array of divisions
    var total = $(".box").length;
    while(total > 0)
    {
              //generating a random number
        erase = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
        $(".box").eq(erase).fadeOut(10000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        total = $(".box").length;
    }
}
```

Later i would also add some time delay between two removals, but for now i just want to know how to remove these boxes one by one.

Comment: What's the question? Does this work or not?

Comment: you do realize you have set the fade out time to 10 seconds right? It will take a good 12 minutes to clear everything

Comment: are these boxes absolutely positioned?  If not, the remaining boxes will reflow when they're removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a little plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.random = function() {
        var n = this.length;
        var r = Math.floor(n * Math.random());
        return n ? $(this[r]) : $();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

usage:

```
(function iterate() {
    $('.box').random().fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        iterate();
    });
})();
```

The elements will disappear one at a time and the loop will automatically terminate when there's no more `.box` elements.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/cddhL/ for demo.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question.

Comment: The last line. His problem is that all boxes disappear at the same time, instead of one after the other.

Comment: WHat happens when `$('.box')` returns an empty list?

Comment: @RoToRa nothing - the loop stops because the `.fadeOut` completion callback never gets invoked on an empty list (I tested it to check that).

Comment: @RoToRa technically the `.random()` plugin tries to evaluate `this[0]` if given an empty list, but the result is `$(undefined)`, i.e. an empty jQuery object.  There's a more strictly correct version in the fiddle.

Comment: I was more refering to the `random()` function. Wnen `this.length` is zero, then it will return `$(undefined)`. That may return an empty list, but that is more of a coincidence than a purposeful termination condition.

Comment: @RoToRa I've updated to make the return explicitly `$()` if the length is zero.

Comment: You should use `Math.round` instead. If you're using `.floor` or `.ceil`, the last or the first element (respectively) will never be removed.

Comment: @Terry you're wrong.  If `n` is 6 (for example) then the range of `n * Math.random()` is `[0, 5.999..]`, which when rounded down gives a range of `[0 .. 5]`, i.e. exactly the range required.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeBoxes(){

    var total = $(".box").length - 1;
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    jQuery(".box:eq('"+randomnumer+"')").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

//this to remove DIV every 5 seconds

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    removeBoxes();    
}, 5000);
```

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You allready know how to trigger something after fading out, namely doing it in the callback where you allready remove the box. Instead of using a loop, write a function that only removes one random box, and call that in the callback.

Example:

```
function removeRandomBox() {
  var boxes = $(".box"); // don't repeatedly search for the boxes
  var total = boxes.length;
  if (length > 0) {
    var erase = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    boxes.eq(erase).fadeOut(10000, function(){
       $(this).remove();
       removeRandomBox();
    });
  }
}
```